# Find the Rotation of an Image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, sift

I have an input image. This image may be rotated or not. But I want to make the image as a non rotated image if there is a rotation.

For this I am planning to use a sample template which is not rotated. My intention is to find the best matching between the input image and this template. And find the angle of rotation of the input image to obtain this best matching. So that using this angle I can re-rotate the input image to original non rotated image.

[image: input image]

[image: sample template]

Comment: Check if image moments are suitable for your images https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment

Comment: @MBo Finding Principal axis using moments and do the rotation accordingly? Seems to be a good solution. I will try. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to find orientation of a picture with delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28403979/how-to-find-orientation-of-a-picture-with-delphi)

Comment: @Neeraj : You need to use EXIF data of image.

Comment: is the template object always within the image and just might be rotated? Or might there be completely different objects in the image?

Comment: @Mika The input image will be always a shirt. And there will be only one shirt in input image. And the template image will be always same... what I have given here.

Comment: I would compute the cv::minAreaRect of the contour and rotate to align it to the axis.

Comment: @Micka I will try that... Thanks

Comment: just tested it, minAreaRect doesnt give expected results for shirts =) afaik internally it uses PCA

Comment: @Micka Yeah I also tested. Not giving desired output

Comment: Background removal and then skeleton matching.

Comment: a few more images may help to find something robust enough

Comment: @Miki you can take any shirt or t-shirt image as input. But the template will be same that I shared

Comment: Any luck with moments so far?

Comment: @Miki The internal stripes affecting the output. I think I need to do this with the outer edges only. Check my output https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5gL866yrGfPMkV1Q1o1SXVqVWs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You need to compute the moments on the binary mask (i.e. everything that is not green)

Comment: @Miki next i tried with this input https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5gL866yrGfPUzdhdU9VNFYtRVk/view?usp=sharing but the output is https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5gL866yrGfPWF9fbXFEeHZUcFE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Miki Ok. I will try with binary mask.