# Need to automatically eliminate noise in image and outer boundary of a object

Tags: image, algorithm, matlab, opencv, image-processing

i am mechanical engineering student working on a project to automatically detect the weld seam (The seam is a edge that is to be welded) present in a workshop. This gives a basic terminology involved in welding (https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfOik.jpg).

[image]
[image]

To separate the weldment from the other objects, i have taken the background image  and subtracted the  foreground image having the weldment  to obatin only the weldment(https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3eg3.jpg). After image subtraction,there are the shadow ,glare and remnant noises  of subtracted background are still present.

[image]

As i want to automatically identify only the weld seam without the outer boundary of weldment, i have tried to detect the edges in the weldment image using canny algorithm  and tried to eliminate the isolated noises using the function bwareopen.I have somehow obtained the approximate boundary of weldment and weld seam. The threshold i have used are purely on trial and error approach as dont know a way to automatically set a threshold to detect them.

The problem  now i am facing is that i cant specify an definite threshold as this algorithm should be able to identify the seam of any material regardless of its surface texture,glare and shadow present there. I need some assistance to remove the glare,shadow and isolated points from the background subtracted image.

Also i need help to get rid of the outer boundary and obtain only smooth weld seam  from starting point to end point.

i have tried to use the following code:

```
a=imread('imageofworkpiece.jpg'); %http://i.imgur.com/3ngu235.jpg

b=imread('background.jpg'); %http://i.imgur.com/DrF6wC2.jpg

Ip = imsubtract(b,a);

imshow(Ip) % weldment separated %https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3eg3.jpg

BW = rgb2gray(Ip);

c=edge(BW,'canny',0.05); % by trial and error

figure;imshow(c) % %http://i.imgur.com/1UQ8E3D.jpg

bw = bwareaopen(c, 100); % by trial and error

figure;imshow(bw) %http://i.imgur.com/Gnjy2aS.jpg
```

Can anybody please suggest me a adaptive way to set a threhold and remove the outer boundary to detect only the seam? Thank you

Comment: *"this algorithm should be able to identify the seam of any material regardless of its surface texture,glare and shadow"* - if you don't already have a PhD, you may be on your way to acquiring one ;-)

Comment: you should add also original image (without markers...) for testing if someone wanted to code/check something before posting it here ... Also you should add more images (the worse the better) to see what light conditions you will have ... there is no such thing as universal algorithm for this yet (or in CV)  we must stick to the specific tasks and conditions to make it work :( and even that is not always possible.

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/q/22187205/2521214 for some additional ideas how to approach this problem ...

Comment: Hi,  i have posted the links to the original images next to the code used as I am not able to post the more than two images directly as i am new to this website.

Comment: Have you played with the lighting? Maybe have the light coming in from the left side only. It should emphasize the butt joint shadow and might make it easier to isolate.

Answer (score 1):

from your image it looks like the weld seam will be usually very dark with sharp intensity edge so why don't you use that ?

1. **do not use background**
2. **create derivation image**

   ```
   dx[y][x]=pixel[y][x]-pixel[y][x-1]
   ```

   do this for whole image (if on place then x must decrease in loop!!!)
3. **filter out all derivations lower then thresholds**

   ```
   if (|dx[y][x]|<threshold) dx[y][x]=0; else pixel[y][x]=255;` // or what ever values you use
   ```
4. **how to obtain threshold value ?**

   compute `min` and `max` intensity and set threshold as `(max-min)*scale` where `scale` is value lower then `1.0` (start with `0.02` or `0.1` for example ...
5. **do this also for `y` axis**

   so compute `dy[][]`... and combine `dx[][]` and `dy[][]` together. Either with `OR` or by `AND` logical functions
6. **filter out artifacts**

   you can use morphologic filters or smooth threshold for this. After all this you will have mask of pixels of weld seam

   if you need boundig box then just loop through all pixels and remember min,max `x,y` coords ...

**[Notes]**

if your images will have good lighting then you can ignore the derivation and threshold the intensity directly with something like:

```
threshold = 0.5*(average_intensity+lowest_intensity)
```

if you want really fully automate this then you have to use adaptive thresholds. So try more thresholds in a loop and remember result closest to desired output based on geometry size,position etc ...

**[edit1] finally have some time/mood for this so**

1. **Intensity image threshold**

   you provided just single image which is far from enough to make reliable algorithm. This is the result

   [image: intensity threshold]

   as you can see without further processing this is not good approach
2. **Derivation image threshold**

   threshold derivation by x (10%)

   [image: di/dx threshold]

   threshold derivation by y (5%)

   [image: di/dy threshold]

   `AND` combination of both 10% di/dx and 1.5% di/dy

   [image: di/dx AND di/dy threshold]

The code in **C++** looks like this (sorry do not use Matlab):

```
int x,y,i,i0,i1,tr2,tr3;

pic1=pic0;      // copy input image pic0 to pic1
pic2=pic0;      // copy input image pic0 to pic2 (just to resize to desired size for derivation)
pic3=pic0;      // copy input image pic0 to pic3 (just to resize to desired size for derivation)
pic1.rgb2i();   // RGB -> grayscale

// abs derivate by x
for (y=pic1.ys-1;y>0;y--)
 for (x=pic1.xs-1;x>0;x--)
    {
    i0=pic1.p[y][x ].dd;
    i1=pic1.p[y][x-1].dd;
    i=i0-i1; if (i<0) i=-i;
    pic2.p[y][x].dd=i;
    }
// compute min,max derivation
i0=pic2.p[1][1].dd; i1=i0;
for (y=1;y<pic1.ys;y++)
 for (x=1;x<pic1.xs;x++)
    {
    i=pic2.p[y][x].dd;
    if (i0>i) i0=i;
    if (i1<i) i1=i;
    }
tr2=i0+((i1-i0)*100/1000);

// abs derivate by y
for (y=pic1.ys-1;y>0;y--)
 for (x=pic1.xs-1;x>0;x--)
    {
    i0=pic1.p[y  ][x].dd;
    i1=pic1.p[y-1][x].dd;
    i=i0-i1; if (i<0) i=-i;
    pic3.p[y][x].dd=i;
    }
// compute min,max derivation
i0=pic3.p[1][1].dd; i1=i0;
for (y=1;y<pic1.ys;y++)
 for (x=1;x<pic1.xs;x++)
    {
    i=pic3.p[y][x].dd;
    if (i0>i) i0=i;
    if (i1<i) i1=i;
    }
tr3=i0+((i1-i0)*15/1000);

// threshold the derivation images and combine them
for (y=1;y<pic1.ys;y++)
 for (x=1;x<pic1.xs;x++)
    {
    // copy original (pic0) pixel for non thresholded areas the rest fill with green color
    if ((pic2.p[y][x].dd>=tr2)&&(pic3.p[y][x].dd>=tr3)) i=0x00FF00;
    else i=pic0.p[y][x].dd;
    pic1.p[y][x].dd=i;
    }
```

`pic0` is input image

`pic1` is output image

`pic2,pic3` are just temporary storage for derivations

`pic?.xy,pic?.ys` is the size of `pic?`

`pic.p[y][x].dd` is pixel axes (dd means access pixel as DWORD ...)

as you can see there is a lot of stuff around (nod visible in the first image you provided) so you need to process this further

- segmentate and separate...,
- use hough transform ...
- filter out small artifacts ...
- identify object by expected geometry properties (aspect ratio,position,size)

**Adaptive thresholds:**

you need for this to know the desired output image properties (not possible to reliably deduce from single image input) then create function that do the above processing with variable `tr2,tr3`. Try in loop more options of `tr2,tr3` (loop through all values or iterate to better results and remember the best output (so you also need some function that detects the quality of output) for example:

```
    quality=0.0; param=0.0; 
    for (a=0.2;a<=0.8;a+=0.1)
     {
     pic1=process_image(pic0,a);
     q=detect_quality(pic1);
     if (q>quality) { quality=q; param=a; pico=pic1; }
     }
```

after this the `pic1` should hold the relatively best threshold image ... You should process like this all threshold separately inside the process_image the targeted threshold must be scaled by `a` for example `tr2=i0+((i1-i0)*a);`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried to use  your algorithm but as i am not that good in programming,there is some error. Could you give me a link to a sample code like you mentioned? Also could you tell me more on how to use a adaptive thresholding?Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well this doesn't solve your problem of finding an automatic thresholding algorithm. but I can help with isolation the seam. The seam is along the y axis (will this always be the case?) so I used hough transform to isolate only near vertical lines. Normally it finds all lines but I restricted the theta search parameter. The code I'm using now happens to highlight the longest line segment (I got it directly [from the matlab website](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/houghlines.html)) and it is coincidentally the weld seam. This was purely coincidental. But using your bwareaopened image as input the hough line detector is able to find the seam. Of course it required a bit of playing around to work, so you are stuck at your original problem of finding optimal settings somehow

Maybe this can be a springboard for someone else
[image]
    a=imread('weldment.jpg'); %https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5Wjx.jpg

```
b=imread('weld_bg.jpg'); %http://i.imgur.com/DrF6wC2.jpg

Ip = imsubtract(b,a);

imshow(Ip) % weldment separated %http://i.imgur.com/v7yBWs1.jpg

BW = rgb2gray(Ip);

c=edge(BW,'canny',0.05); % by trial and error
bw = bwareaopen(c, 100); % by trial and error

figure(1);imshow(c) ;title('canny') % %http://i.imgur.com/1UQ8E3D.jpg
figure(2);imshow(bw);title('bw area open') %http://i.imgur.com/Gnjy2aS.jpg

[H,T,R] = hough(bw,'RhoResolution',1,'Theta',-15:5:15);
figure(3)
imshow(H,[],'XData',T,'YData',R,...
            'InitialMagnification','fit');
xlabel('\theta'), ylabel('\rho');
axis on, axis normal, hold on;
P  = houghpeaks(H,5,'threshold',ceil(0.5*max(H(:))));
x = T(P(:,2)); y = R(P(:,1));
plot(x,y,'s','color','white');
% Find lines and plot them
lines = houghlines(BW,T,R,P,'FillGap',2,'MinLength',30);
figure(4), imshow(BW), hold on
max_len = 0;
for k = 1:length(lines)
   xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
   plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','green');

   % Plot beginnings and ends of lines
   plot(xy(1,1),xy(1,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','yellow');
   plot(xy(2,1),xy(2,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','red');

   % Determine the endpoints of the longest line segment
   len = norm(lines(k).point1 - lines(k).point2);
   if ( len > max_len)
      max_len = len;
      xy_long = xy;
   end
end

% highlight the longest line segment
plot(xy_long(:,1),xy_long(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','blue');
```